# How do I center a schema in LaTeX?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, schemata

This is  my first question in this amazing community, thanks in advance for the help.

I am using the package `schemata` and the `exam` document class. I want to center a schema I have created. Could anyone help me with this? I attach the code and an image:

```
\schema[closed]{
    \schemabox{$e'\ast e=e'$ (por ser $e$ neutro)\\$e\ast e'=e$ (por ser $e'$ neutro)}
    }{
    \schemabox{$\Rightarrow\hspace{2pt}e'=e$}
    }\par
\vspace{1cm}
```

[image]

Update: I found that if the previous line is centered and I code the schema like this (adding a null hspace)

```
\hspace{0cm}\schema[closed]{
    \schemabox{$e'\ast e=e'$ (por ser $e$ neutro)\\$e\ast e'=e$ (por ser $e'$ neutro)}
    }{
    \schemabox{$\Rightarrow\hspace{2pt}e'=e$}
    }\par
```

, then I get it:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the schema in an unnumbered display-math setting. (The vertical lines at the edges of the following screenshot are drawn because the `showframe` package is loaded.) By placing the schema in a displaymath setting, you can get omit the `\par` and `\vspace{1cm}` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{schemata}
\usepackage{showframe} % draw frame lines around the text block

\begin{document}

\[
\schema[closed]{
    \schemabox{$e'\ast e=e'$ (por ser $e$ neutro)\\
               $e\ast e'=e$ (por ser $e'$ neutro)}
    }{
    \schemabox{$\Rightarrow e'=e$}
    }
\]
\end{document}
```